# how to clear a text box in Win32 C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am making a notepad in C++, and I want to clear the text box when a certain button is clicked. I can't take the text box from the `WinMain()` function from the `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {...}` where my text box is. This is the code for my text box 
`HWND hWndEdit = CreateWindow(TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WB_LEFT | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE, 0, 0, 1366, 768, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);`
I've tried googling to no avail, mulled over many forums, and even placed the text box inside the `LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {...}`, and using `SetWindowText(hWndEdit, _T(""))`, which causes my program to freeze. I am not sure on what to do. Putting the text box code back in the WinMain function stops it from freezing, but then I can't clear it anymore. What can I do?

If you need all my code here it is.

```
// compile with: /D_UNICODE /DUNICODE /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /c

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// Global variables
HMENU menuStrip;

// The main window class name.
static TCHAR szWindowClass[] = _T("DesktopApp");

// The string that appears in the application's title bar.
static TCHAR szTitle[] = _T("NoteRecorder");

HINSTANCE hInst;

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

void AddMenuStrip(HWND hWnd);

int WINAPI WinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow
)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, L"");
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to RegisterClassEx failed!"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    hInst = hInstance;

    // Height and width
    int x = 1366;
    int y = 768;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        x, y,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );

    


    if (!hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,
            _T("Call to CreateWindow failed!"),
            _T("NoteRecorder"),
            NULL);

        return 1;
    }

    // The parameters to ShowWindow explained:
    // hWnd: the value returned from CreateWindow
    // nCmdShow: the fourth parameter from WinMain
    ShowWindow(hWnd,
        nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    // Main message loop:
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    
    HWND hWndEdit = CreateWindow(TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WB_LEFT | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE, 0, 0, 1366, 768, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case 11:
            SetWindowText(hWndEdit, _T(""));
            MessageBox(NULL,
                _T("The function has executed successfully."),
                _T("NoteRecorder"),            

                MB_ICONASTERISK);
            break;
        case 12:
            break;
        case 13:
            break;
        case 14:
            break;
        case 15:
            break;
        
        case 21:
            break;
        case 22:
            break;
        case 23:
            break;
        case 24:
            break;
        case 25:
            break;
        case 26:
            break;

        case 31:
            break;
        case 41:
            break;
        case 42:
            break;
        }


        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
        AddMenuStrip(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}

void AddMenuStrip(HWND hWnd)
{
    menuStrip = CreateMenu();
    HMENU fileMenu = CreateMenu();
        AppendMenu(fileMenu, MF_STRING, 11, L"New");
        AppendMenu(fileMenu, MF_STRING, 12, L"Open");
        AppendMenu(fileMenu, MF_STRING, 13, L"Save");
        AppendMenu(fileMenu, MF_STRING, 14, L"Save As");
        AppendMenu(fileMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);
        AppendMenu(fileMenu, MF_STRING, 15, L"Exit");
    HMENU editMenu = CreateMenu();
        AppendMenu(editMenu, MF_STRING, 21, L"Undo");
        AppendMenu(editMenu, MF_STRING, 22, L"Redo");
        AppendMenu(editMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);
        AppendMenu(editMenu, MF_STRING, 23, L"Cut");
        AppendMenu(editMenu, MF_STRING, 24, L"Copy");
        AppendMenu(editMenu, MF_STRING, 25, L"Paste");
        AppendMenu(editMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);
        AppendMenu(editMenu, MF_STRING, 26, L"Select All");
    HMENU formatMenu = CreateMenu();
        AppendMenu(formatMenu, MF_BYCOMMAND, 31, L"Font...");
    HMENU helpMenu = CreateMenu();
        AppendMenu(helpMenu, MF_STRING, 41, L"Get Help");
        AppendMenu(helpMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);
        AppendMenu(helpMenu, MF_STRING, 42, L"About WorkPlace 247...");
    // Menu Items for the MenuStrip
    AppendMenu(menuStrip, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)fileMenu, L"File");
    AppendMenu(menuStrip, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)editMenu, L"Edit");
    AppendMenu(menuStrip, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)formatMenu, L"Format");
    AppendMenu(menuStrip, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)helpMenu, L"Help");

    SetMenu(hWnd, menuStrip);
}
```

I am using VS2019 MSVC, with Win32.

I'm also really bad at C++, and I want to learn. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show the code that creates `hWndEdit` and that is trying to use it. Is it the "same" variable?

Comment: I highly recommend a different GUI framework than MSVC.  wxWidgets and Qt are good.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  Using `SetWindowText(hWndEdit, _T(""))` should work just fine when used *correctly*. On a side note, `WB_LEFT` is not a window style that you can pass to `CreateWindow()`, it is an action code used with the `EDITWORDBREAKPROC` callback instead. You probably meant to use `ES_LEFT` instead.

Comment: OK I'll do that then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
HWND hWndEdit = CreateWindow(TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | WB_LEFT | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE, 0, 0, 1366, 768, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

That edit control will be created every time your main window gets ANY message, quickly running out of resources.

You only need to create it once (for example, in response to `WM_CREATE` message), and save that window handle in some static (or global) variable, so that you can use it later.

One way: add this to your "Global" section

```
// Global variables
HMENU menuStrip;
HWND hWndEdit = 0; // <- new line
```

then move a call to create that control into `WM_CREATE` handler:

```
case WM_CREATE:
    AddMenuStrip(hWnd);
    hWndEdit = CreateWindow(TEXT("EDIT"), TEXT(""), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | ES_AUTOVSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE, 0, 0, 1366, 768, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    break;
```

Comment: Exactly how? I am not good at this stuff. But I did see in task manager that when i kept it open for a long time it would take up to 500 MB ram

Comment: @user16709023 please see updated answer. Also, RAM is not your problem here, you will sooner run out of window handles

Comment: @user16709023 `CreateWindow()` will send a `WM_CREATE` message to your `WndProc()`. That is the time when you should create child controls, like your `Edit` window. That way, they are created only 1 time. Then, on *subsequent* messages, like in response to a button click, you can access and update that single existing `Edit` control as needed.

Comment: @user16709023 not sure I understand your question. The local variable in a function gets created every time the function is called, so your original code created a LOT of edit windows. The `WM_CREATE` message is only sent once to a window, so my code created only one (and assigned that window handle to a global variable). Alternatively, you could simply add a word `static` to your `HWND hWndEdit = CreateWindow(`, like `static HWND hWndEdit = CreateWindow(...)` to only initialize it once. Did it answer your question? If no - could you re-state it? And if yes - could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

WndProc is called everytime event occures like (mouse move, click, size, paint...)
so an hWndEdit is created every message, that's the problem
you can do this:

1. you can keep it there but make it `static`
2. create `hWndEdit` in `WinMain`, give it ID, then in `WM_COMMAND` call `hWndEdit = GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID)`
3. create `hWndEdit` in `WM_CREATE` and do the same as in step two
4. make `hWndEdit` global and create it in `WinMain`, `WM_CREATE` or at any stage

Comment: This answer gave me more info about C++. More so than the last one. But I still think the last one was the better answer.